# ColdFusion XMLParse giving element not bound. Works locally

Tags: xml, coldfusion, namespaces

I am upgrading some SAML1 SSO code to SAML2.  Not a giant difference, and I have the code working on a local server with the same configuration (jrun/multiple deployments, CF7) as the actual servers.

While my code works great locally, up on the servers it is throwing:
The prefix "samlp" for element "samlp:Response" is not bound. I'm stripped the offending page down to just that line, and that seems to be the brick wall.  I've tried removing the namespace, but if you know SAML the spec is just RIDDLED with namespaces.

```
<cfscript>
xmlResponse = trim(form.SAMLResponse);
docElement= XmlParse(variables.xmlResponse);
</cfscript>
```

The stripped the XML down to the important bits.  This still gives the error-

```
<samlp:Response ID="_74747ca7-7188-45c0-85a0-30177d868923"
            Version="2.0"
            IssueInstant="2013-03-21T11:26:59.320Z"
            Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
            xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
            >
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://test.com/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

I am completely at a loss. Any ideas, guys?

Comment: Can you do a diff on the output of `form.SAMLResponse` between the local and remote servers to see if there's anything off about the response?

Comment: I just did that - and it was something absolutely simple and stupid.  There is a upstream XSS filter that stripped out part of the ns comment.  I feel like a fool now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you verify that xmlns:samlp is not being delcared differently elsewhere? What you have above looks like it should work. That's the XML you tested correct? This post might be somewhat helpful, but I don't think it's duplicate if the above is accurate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892617/prefix-for-element-not-bound.

Comment: When something doesn't work in another environment, it's invariably a config issue or a data issue. Glad we could help narrow it down.